# Как обратиться к оригинальному стилю кокнтрола TreeViewItem для изменения фигуры стрелки в Avalonia

Tags: c#, mvvm, style, avalonia, reactive

На текущий у меня есть код который меняет размер стрелок в TreeViewItem, но мне нужно стрелки изменить на тупоугольный равнобедренный треугольник. Мне кажется должно быть что то вроде такого, но это не работает.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <StreamGeometry x:Key="TreeViewItemCollapsedChevronPathData">M 1,0 10,10 1,0 Z</StreamGeometry>
        <StreamGeometry x:Key="TreeViewItemExpandedChevronPathData">M 0,0 15,0 0,30 Z</StreamGeometry>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Styles>
        <Style Selector="ToggleButton.ExpandCollapseChevron /template/ Path#ChevronPath">
            <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemCollapsedChevronPathData}" />
        </Style>
        <Style Selector="ToggleButton.ExpandCollapseChevron:checked /template/ Path#ChevronPath">
            <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemExpandedChevronPathData}" />
        </Style>
        <Style Selector="TreeViewItem /template/ ToggleButton#PART_ExpandCollapseChevron">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"></Setter>
        </Style>
</Window.Styles>
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось самостоятельно.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <StreamGeometry x:Key="TreeViewItemCollapsedChevronPathData">M 0,0 15,15 0,30 Z</StreamGeometry>
        <StreamGeometry x:Key="TreeViewItemExpandedChevronPathData">M 0,0 30,0 15,15 Z</StreamGeometry>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Styles>
        <Style Selector="ToggleButton:checked /template/ Path#ChevronPath">
            <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemExpandedChevronPathData}" />
        </Style>
        <Style Selector="ToggleButton:unchecked /template/ Path#ChevronPath">
            <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemCollapsedChevronPathData}" />
        </Style>
        <Style Selector="TreeViewItem /template/ ToggleButton#PART_ExpandCollapseChevron">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Styles>
```